# Late evaluation in c#?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, lazy-evaluation

I am working on an application in c#. To make this application work, I have found myself doing some things that feel quite unnatural for the language I have selected. After going through many refactorings and refinements, I have come to the realization that the functionality that I am trying to implement is really a form of ‘lazy evaluation’ (I think). This is what I would like...

```
// Criteria 1: Lazy evaluation of expressions
int x = LazyEvaluated.New<int>();
int y = LazyEvaluated.New<int>();
int z = LazyEvaluated.New<int>();

z.Assign(x + y);
Assert.ThrowsException(z.Evalutate());
x.Assign(1);
Assert.ThrowsException(z.Evalutate());
y.Assign(2);
Assert.Equals(3, z.Evaluate());
x.Assign(3);
Assert.Equals(5, z.Evaluate());

// Criteria 2: Referencing relative to parent object    
Car myCar = LazyEvaluated.New<Car>();
Engine engineInMyCar = LazyEvaluated.New<Engine>();
double displacementOfMyEngine = LazyEvaluated.New<double>();

engineInMyCar = myCar.Engine;
displacementOfMyEngine = engineInMyCar.Displacement;

Car subaru = new Car(new FlatFourEngine());
Car falcon = new Car(new InlineSixEngine());

myCar.Assign(subaru);
Assert.IsTypeOf<FlatFourEngine>(engineInMyCar.Evaluate());
Assert.IsEqual(2.0, displacementOfMyEngine.Evaluate());

myCar.Assign(falcon);
Assert.IsTypeOf<InlineSixEngine>(engineInMyCar.Evaluate());
Assert.IsEqual(4.0, displacementOfMyEngine.Evaluate());
```

And these are the simple class definitions that I have used for illustration...

```
public class Car {
    private readonly Engine engine;            
    public Car(Engine engine) { this.engine = engine; }
    public Engine Engine { get { return engine; } }
}

public abstract class Engine {
    public abstract double Displacement { get; }
}        

public class FlatFourEngine : Engine {
    public override double Displacement { get { return 2.0; } }
}

public class InlineSixEngine : Engine {
    public override double Displacement { get { return 4.0; } }
}
```

The reason I want this functionality is mostly for separation-of-concerns. To illustrate, let’s take the car analogue a bit further. My car is made up of lots of bits; engine, tyres, interior etc. My tyres need to be changed every 2 years by a tyre shop. My engine needs to have an oil change every 6 months by a mechanic. The interior needs to be vacuumed every 3 months by a detailer. It would be nice to able to do something along the lines of...

```
tyreShop.ReplaceTyres(myCar.Tyres, every2Years);
mechanic.ChangeOil(myCar.Engine, every6Months);
detailer.VacuumInterior(myCar.Interior, every3Months);
```

Some reasons for this approach;

- I would like to set-and-forget. Once I schedule a part of my car in for a service, I want it to happen on an ongoing basis without any further input from me.
- I don’t want to have to call each of my service centres and notify them the instant that I purchase a new car. In fact, they don’t need to know that I have a new car until it comes time for a service. If they try to service my car and it doesn’t exist, then it’s ok for them to throw an exception.
- I want each of my services to be as simple and focussed as possible. Why give the tyre shop a reference to my entire car (including engine, interior, etc), when the only thing they really care about is the tyres?
- I don’t want the tyreshop to give me a new set of tyres and force me to fit (assign) them to the car myself.

I do not have any formal education in CS, and my only programming experience is with c & c# languages. I’ve just spent the last 6 months getting familiar with c# & .Net. For the most part, I really like the language and early-evaluation in general. But I am now questioning whether I would have been better off tackling my particular problem in a different language with inbuilt support for lazy evaluation.

My questions are;

1. If I were to start again, what would be the best language to tackle such a problem in?
2. Are there any existing platforms for c# that provide support for lazy evaluation?
3. What are the alternatives for making this work in c#? Are there any particular design patterns I should read up on?

Comment: +1 for a very well formed question. About the matter at hand, I think "shops" can and should be given a reference to the entire car: if you need a tyre change, you bring your car to the shop, you don't usually take the tyres down yourself and go change them :) Also, if your "shops" handle a `Car` reference, you can make up a `Shop` superclass for them to inherit from, which can handle common tasks (thus allowing you to DRY). Not to mention (to keep close to your example) this allows to interesting behavior, like shops passing around your `Car` to perform various tasks on it.

Comment: @alex: Thanks for the response. Fair point - it doesn’t seem unreasonable to give a tyre shop my whole car to replace the tyres. But what if I had a deeper object hierarchy as follows… `tyreShop.ReplaceTyres(myFamily.Wife.Car, every2Years)`. Giving the TyreShop a reference to myFamily definitely doesn't feel right. But there is a chance that I might do `myFamily.Wife = new Person() { Car = new VWGolf(); }` if I catch her cheating with the milk man. In this case, the instance of Car that was given to the TyreShop needs to be updated to reflect the car of my new wife.

Comment: I note that I have been somewhat contorting my example in response to people’s suggestions, and I apologize for doing this. I’ve found it a little difficult to capture the true complexities of my domain in a simple example. I will wait some time and then accept the response that best addresses the actual question/example I posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you're *really* after is scheduling an action to take place later, repeatedly. I'd suggest that delegates - probably using lambda expressions - are the most appropriate approach for this:

```
scheduler.Schedule(every3Months, () => tyreShop.ReplaceTyres(myCar));
```

This way the only piece of your code which needs to know about the laziness aspect is the scheduler itself. All the rest of your code can assume that when you call a method, you want that action to take place right now, which is much more idiomatic C#.

Comment: This is a good solution for the simple example I posted in the question. If there is a single scheduler then I can make the scheduler resolve all dependencies before passing them to the services. But suppose now I have a Body shop that fixes my car after a prang; bodyShop.FixChassis(myCar, myCar.AfterAccident). In my actual application I have many such triggers (some time-based, some event-based) which can cause a service to execute. If I change my car, I don't want to have to manually track down every singe scheduler/trigger in order to give it the new instance of my car.

Comment: @knick: I suspect at this point the analogy is suitably tortured compared with what I imagine your *real* requirements are, that we can't sensibly make concrete suggestions. For example, you could use `bodyShop.FixChassis(me.MyCar)` instead, which would always get your "current car" when the delegate is executed... but I don't know whether that really maps to your project.

Comment: Today I learned that the British spelling of "tire" is "tyre"

Answer (score 4):

.NET 4 has inbuilt support for lazy initialization using `Lazy` see the documentation on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: I have read up on this, but I don't think it is quite what I am after. The Lazy<T> type only seems to provide support for lazy _initialization_. What I would like it support for the more general lazy _evaluation_. If I do Lazy<Car>.Value.Engine, the engine it gives me will not be lazy. Also, I want my lazy object to have the same Type as the object that gets assigned to it (not Lazy<T>).